# Data Validation Input Message workaround 255 char

Tags: excel, textbox, validation, vba

I am trying to create a workaround for the `Data Validation Input Message`, since my input message is more than 255 chars.
I have tried http://contextures.com/xlDataVal12.html but the `text box` is fixed. I would need the text box or label to move with the selected cell.

On the image below, you can see the issue. We cannot display the whole message within the input box.

[1 http://img5013.photobox.co.uk/42779160c8143d2fcab8c396d411e8b621181c1be9f1a01fb62e272d26debaf4b53f7657.jpg](http://img5013.photobox.co.uk/42779160c8143d2fcab8c396d411e8b621181c1be9f1a01fb62e272d26debaf4b53f7657.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Contextures code, you need to set the `.Top` and `.Left` properties of the shape to the same properties of a cell. Here's a rewrite of that code that moves the textbox near the cell.

```
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
' modified by Dick Kusleika 7/21/2015
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sTitle As String
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim sMsgAdd As String
    Dim tbxTemp As Shape
    Dim lDVType As Long
    Dim lRowMsg As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set ws = Target.Parent
    Set tbxTemp = ws.Shapes("txtInputMsg")

    On Error Resume Next
        lDVType = 0
        lDVType = Target.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    If lDVType = 0 Then
        tbxTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = vbNullString
        tbxTemp.Visible = msoFalse
    Else
        If Len(Target.Validation.InputTitle) > 0 Or Len(Target.Validation.InputMessage) > 0 Then

            sTitle = Target.Validation.InputTitle & vbLf

            On Error Resume Next
                lRowMsg = 0
                lRowMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Validation.InputTitle, Sheets("MsgText").Columns(1), 0)
                If lRowMsg > 0 Then
                    sMsgAdd = Me.Parent.Sheets("MsgText").Cells(lRowMsg, 2).Value
                End If
            On Error GoTo errHandler

            sMsg = Target.Validation.InputMessage
            With tbxTemp.TextFrame
                .Characters.Text = sTitle & sMsg & vbLf & sMsgAdd
                .Characters.Font.Bold = False
                .Characters(1, Len(sTitle)).Font.Bold = True
            End With
            tbxTemp.Top = Target.Offset(1, 1).Top
            tbxTemp.Left = Target.Offset(1, 1).Left
            tbxTemp.Visible = msoTrue
            tbxTemp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
        Else
            tbxTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = vbNullString
            tbxTemp.Visible = msoFalse
        End If
    End If

errHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Dick it´s working like a charm!! Thank you so much. Can you just help me get the text box to the front, so it will be shown on text. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Added a zOrder line to the code that will bring the textbox to the front. Autofit is a little tougher. You could fix the height and try to adjust the width based on the number of characters `.Width = .TextFrame.Characters.Count / 5 * 6:.Height = 100`. You'd have to play with the numbers to see what works.

Comment: Bah, Excel already thought of it (and you probably did too). Right click on the textbox, choose Properties, choose TextBox, and check `Resize to fit text`